# Java error: converting to the same type

Tags: java, weka

Type mismatch: cannot convert from Instance to Instance

```
DataSource source = new DataSource("C:/Users/EP/Desktop/epark60/vote.arff");
        Instances data = source.getDataSet();
        if (data.classIndex() == -1)
          data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);

        Instance[] instances =  new Instance[data.numInstances()];
        for (int i = 0; i < instances.length; i++) {
            instances[i] = data.instance(i);    //<-- error @ data.instance(i);
        }
```

data.instance(i); gives Instance and i want to put into instances array but it gives me error above.

why can it not just store but have to convert to the same type (instance to instance)??

Comment: Are you dealing with 2 different `Instance` classes? Like `com.example.Instance` and `net.other.Instance`?

Comment: Please give more context. My *guess* is that you've accidentally declared a type parameter called Instance. Are you using generics by any chance?

Comment: @jlordo you are absolutely right. i see that i have two different types of Instance class from two different packages. okay thank you!